# jQuery-1.4.2 invalid argument line 4618 value=NaNpx in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Many people seem to have run into this exception in jQuery.extend:

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 4618
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: https://windev/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js

My issue is that within our dev team we are all running IE8 but only my machine has this js error.  The same code is running on all machines. If the error showed up on all of the machines I would apply one of the solutions that has been posted. Since it is only on one machine in the group, I am wondering whether anyone has found an IE setting or an add in that may cause this exception and explain why it is not happening consistently across the team.

Comment: Make sure that your copy of IE8 is not running in IE7 mode.

Comment: I'd echo @Pointy's suggestion -- it's one of the most common reasons for weird problems in IE8 that only affect some machines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked, and I am running in IE8 mode.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if not all browsers are configured the same way, more specifically in the Advanced tab in Internet Options. There is section in the Advanced tab that lets you toggle on/off notifications about errors in your scripts, it is possible that these have been unchecked and that is why only one of your machines is getting the error.

Look at Method 1 in this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260

Comment: Script debugging is already disabled on the machine with the error, so I don't think that's the answer.

Comment: Is the option to 'display a notification on every script error' checked?